# order by Enumerable list not giving the wanted results

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have list of dates:

```
var dates = (from var in variants.AsEnumerable()
     where var.Field<DateTime>("ShowDate").AddHours(-2) > DateTime.Now
     select var.Field<DateTime>("ShowDate").getPresentationFormat()).OrderBy(t => DateTime.Parse(t)).Distinct();
```

I need that if the user selected one of the dates, the list of the dates will be with the selected value as first value.
The following did not work. Why?

```
 if (Request.Cookies["Selected_Date"] != null)
 {
     var s= Request.Cookies["Selected_Date"].Value;
     dates.OrderBy(x => x.Equals(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

- you don't use the return value of the OrderBy method
- the selected value will be the last, not the first because true sorts after false

So an improved version would be:

```
var result = dates.OrderBy(x => !x.Equals(s))
```